# How to add id to a href generated by ember.js linkto?

Tags: ember.js

I have a template that has a a tag with an id and based on id the css applies style to this a href. I would like to use the LinkTo helper for this tag and id set to the one it has now. Helper LinkTo in Ember generates a link. I need to set an id on this a link for example:

```
<a href='...' id=xyz>
```

How to acomplish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just pass HTML attributes to the `linkTo` helper:

```
{{#linkTo 'some.route' id="xyz"}}Link text{{/linkTo}}
```